# ZwQueryKey with KeyNameInformation alternative for XP?

Tags: c, windows, callback, registry, kernel

I'm writing a kernel driver which registers registry routines callback through CmRegisterCallbackEx. I want to get key full path and print it through DbgPrint. In the callback, I successfully query the Key pointer using ZwQueryKey with KeyNameInformation flag, but in KEY_NAME_INFORMATION structure's documentation I read that:

> Available in Windows Vista and later versions of the Windows
>   operating system.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff553381(v=vs.85).aspx

So is there any way to get full registry path in kernel in windows xp? I know it's possible because SysInternals tools already has this functionality and it works fine in xp.

Thanks

UPDATE

---

I just tried acquiring key full path using KeyNameInformation flag on XP SP2 (as MSDN states, this flag is not supported on XP, see  link above) and to my biggest surprise, it worked. Anyone knows why MSDN states that this flag is not supported? Is it a simple error or I misunderstood something?

Thanks.

Comment: Try to tag your programming language which makes easier to help..

Comment: My guess is it is not supported because XP is EOL?

Comment: @hellork, what do you mean by EOL? Actually, looks like it is perfectly supported. This is an error in the documentation probably. I already reported it and hope they fill fix

Comment: End of Life, as in they may have supported it in the past, but now they no longer care about XP in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is entirely possible that support for KeyNameInformation was added in a patch/inline.  The question is, what are you going to do on XP SP0?

You might want to consider using ObReferenceObjectByHandle() to obtain the KEY object from your key handle, and follow that with ObQueryObjectName().

Comment: Wow, same answer here on SO as they got on [MSDN forums](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wdk/thread/07495c27-6b33-4235-973e-f79c6fe7090c).